# How to restrict broadcasting to a single client with Atmosphere

Tags: java, atmosphere

I'm trying to use Atmosphere for a client server communication. I've read the message here on stackoverflow about one-to-one chat and the relevant page on the Atmosphere Wiki "Creating private channel of communication between Browsers" but i'm still stuck. Though i'm creating a 'private' channel for each uuid the messages are received in other browsers too that connect to the same URL.

In my scenario i need to restrict the communication between a single browser client and the server.

Answer (score 1):

I managed to solve the problem by adding a unique key to the request URI and using a URI template as suggested in the multichat example.

@ManagedService(path = "/msg/{xfid}")

and

```
@PathParam("xfid")``
private String xfSession;
```

Then i used the path param to lookup a specific Broadcaster

```
 Broadcaster privateChannel = BroadcasterFactory.getDefault().lookup(xfSession,true);
```

Now updates send from the server are only broadcasted to the client associated with the path param.